# SQL auto_increment behaviour

Tags: mysql, sql, database, auto-increment

My first question is:

- Can I manually input ID into an auto_increment column of a table?
  For example: I have 10 records with ID from 1 to 10. Can I manually input the 11 record with the ID of 3 (yes, it's a duplication!)

My second question is:

- I assume that it's possible to manually input ID number, what if I have 9 record with ID from 1 - 9, and my 10th record have the ID of 11. Is the "Auto_increment" gonna skip it to go to 12, or it will add another 11?

I know I didn't express it so well, but I'm confused and hope someone can help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No you can't. An auto_increment column can't contain duplicates and is often used as a primary key. It's possible to have a non-PK auto_increment column as long as you have index on it. There can be only one auto_increment column per table.
2. Yes, it's possible to insert a value manually into auto_increment field. It will start at MAX value + 1. Therefore you'll have a gap in sequence.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0867d1/1)** demo

Further reading **[Using AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)**

Comment: Note: auto_increment doesn't technically *need* to be the PK (this answer notes *should*); although it is often used for such a surrogate-PK purpose and plays well with physical layout - all Key columns/tuples must be uniquely identify a column and cannot contain duplicates.

Comment: @user2246674 Fair enough. Specifically mentioned that in the updated answer.